# Ambiguous: 'HubConnectionExtensions.On( HubConnection, string, Action)' and 'HubConnectionExtensions.On(HubConnection, string, Func<T1, Task>)'

Tags: c#-4.0, signalr, ambiguous

Here is an example of where I am getting the error

```
Connection.On<ViewAcknowledgementRequestSpecifier>("ReceiveAcknowledgementRequest", ReceiveAcknowledgementRequest);
Connection.On<ViewDelayRequestSpecifier>("ReceiveDelayRequest", ReceiveDelayRequest);
Connection.On<InfoRequestSpecifier>("ReceiveInfoRequest", ReceiveInfoRequest);
```